# Is it possible write, publish and edit posts with Wordpress from console aka terminal?

Tags: xml-rpc

I would like to write things like LaTex with Wordpress i.e. a title would be a section, to use vimlatex -plugin to speed up writing etc. Also, it would be cool if I could publish things without going into the Graphical interface. I like to use my own editor and see things in the directory level. Is there some easy way to write things there without opening a browser?

Suppose I had 3 categories: A) Fun, B) Future and B) Past. My writing directory would look like this

```
$ pwd
/home/h/Wrtiing
$ tree
.
├── fun
│   ├── chess
│   ├── climbing_game
│   ├── go
│   └── zero_match
├── future
│   └── project_improbable
└── past
    ├── test1
    └── test2
```

then with permissions `$ chmod +r fun/go` or some other way, I could publish things. I could change permission the day when I want to publish something. Is there something this dead easy done with WordPress?

Comment: Look at http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support and the dozens of projects that work with WordPress from the outside. Not the exact concept of chmodding and directories but when there's a will there's a way.

Comment: How about this one? https://github.com/andreascreten/wp-cli

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not used these, I'm sure one of them will help out.

http://scott.yang.id.au/2002/12/mtsendpy/

http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-library/ (think download is an external link)

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/xmlrpclib/